# How to fix "abort" issue in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a project in Django. I have installed python 3.7.5 and Django 1.11. When I try to run the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I am getting

```
[1] abort      python manage.py migrate
```

The same thing is happening for

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I have been brainstorming for the last 2 days on how to fix this issue but no luck. Can someone help me out here in fixing this issue?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Is this an exact error message?

Comment: @funnydman Yes. You can check the screenshot I just added

Comment: If you are using MAC.OS this [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775605/django-running-manage-py-always-aborts) may help you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally got the answer for this question. It is frustrating to know that new version of macOS Catalina (10.15) only has this issue. Issue is related to cryptography which require OpenSSL. To fix these issues follow these steps:

1. Run `brew install openssl`
2. `cd /usr/local/lib`
3. Search for the file which has the name like libcrypto.dylib. For OpenSSL version 1.0.0 the path will be `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`, and for OpenSSL 1.1.1 the path will be `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib`
4. Also search path for libssl.dylib
5. Run the following commands with the paths that you found:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.dylib

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib libssl.dylib
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. Now I am able to connect to  Django server and resume my pending work.

Answer (score 0):

For openssl version: `1.1.1k` what worked for me was this:

```
 1. cd /usr/local/lib
 2. ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.dylib
 3. ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib libssl.dylib
```