# Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way on macOS 10.15.1

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, openssl, libcrypto

Whenever I use the AWS CLI, which obviously uses Python, I get the following error.

```
aws --version
WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into an error.
aws-cli/1.16.15 Python/2.7.16 Darwin/19.0.0 botocore/1.12.5
```

I am running it on macOS 10.15.1 (19B88), kernel version: Darwin 19.0.0.

My application is running on Python 2 (for now) so I can't upgrade Python quite yet.

Is this caused by running a soon-to-be-unsupported version of Python?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

should resolve this for you. It has worked for me.

See more at: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4708#issuecomment-567232285

Comment: It didn't work for me at first, I've got `WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.` I was able to fix it with: `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip` and then `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL`

Comment: @hit3k Thanks, I have updated the question to reflect this.