# My Python program is warning me that lib crypto is loaded in unsafe way

Tags: python, libcrypto

My Python program is warning me that lib crypto is loaded in an unsafe way and aborts the task:

```
WARNING: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way
[1]    3032 abort      python manager.py
```

What can I do or what exactly does this mean?

I am using a Mac with M1 chip and Python 3.8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way on macOS 10.15.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081569/executing-a-script-that-is-loading-libcrypto-in-an-unsafe-way-on-macos-10-15-1)

Comment: No it does not. I already tried to install and reinstall cryptography

Comment: and openssl and a few more but nothing works for me