# Django: python manage.py runserver abort

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a repo locally but facing an issue i.e python manage.py runserver command gets aborted as soon as I hit localhost URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/)

error - **[1]    7398 abort      python manage.py runserver**

Django version 1.6.6
Python 2.7
OS -> MacOS Catalina (10.15.3)
Database postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.2

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback, please?

Comment: there is only one line in error which I already posted.

Answer (score 1):

first why ur using old version python and Django. that's first because they didn't have support so I strongly recommend you to upgrade newest versions

Comment: In my organization, our codebase is on old version only.

Comment: then add more info about error pls so i will try help you. plus you need to check virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to Python & Catalina incompatibility. Try using Python 3.7. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775605/django-running-manage-py-always-aborts)

In general, try to avoid using Python 2.x. Insted use Python 3.7.x.